# can we share data through app directly to a google plus page?

Tags: android

I have itegrate google+ with my android app. I want to share some data directly to a page already present on google plus. is this possible to post on a google plus page?

Comment: Check this: http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.in/2013/05/google-plus-integration-in-android.html

Comment: How many similar answers with freshly created accounts is this question going to have?

Answer (score 0):

No we can not post directly to other page on google plus. we can only comment on the post of other pages or users on google plus.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to share post on other page in google plus. Google does not provide the facility to share post on other page. user can post data only to their profile and share it. user can only leave their comment on other pages post but can't post directly to other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Like Facebook, Google plus does not provide the facility to post data on other pages. we can post only on our profile and can share it publicly but can post on other pages but can leave comment on the post of other pages.